# How to setup your own smtp mail server in windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, smtp, iis-6

I am trying to setup an mail server without using my ISP's server on my local machine. I found that microsoft IIS can provide this facility but I am no getting the right way to do this.
I also want that every computer in my LAN can connect to my SMTP server to send email to internet. What properties should I set in the properties field of SMTP Virtual server and also the settings of email client.
I am using xp professionnal, IIS 6.0 and microsoft outlook. Please guide me in this issue.
Thankyou

Comment: Unless you have a a "business" account with your ISP this is probably not allowed, and any emails you try to send will possibly be blocked.

Comment: ok. but can I send mail locally in my lan like we do in internet.

Comment: Yes you can, what you do on your own lan is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this article & references at the end: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308161

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Ivo Flipse: What about copyright issues and size issues? While I understand the desire, unfortunately I don't think it's always practical (or legal).

Comment: Then you resort to paraphrasing or summarizing the steps, but only posting a link would mean link rot would render the answer completely useless @martineau

Answer (score 1):

**Steps to install the SMTP server**

1. Firstly, from the Start menu, click Control Panel.
2. Go to Add or Remove Programs.
3. From the left pane, click Add/Remove Windows Components.
4. From the Components list, click Application Server, and then click Details.
5. From the Sub components of Application Server list, click Internet
       Information Services (IIS), and then click Details.
6. From the Sub components of Internet Information Services (IIS) list,
       select the SMTP Service check box.
7. Click OK.
8. Click Next. You might be prompted for the Windows Server 2003 family
       CD or the network install path.
9. Click Finish.

**To configure global SMTP settings**

1. In IIS Manager, expand the local computer, right-click Default SMTP
   Virtual Server, and click Properties.
2. Change the default settings on the property pages as needed. For
   information about individual settings, click Help.

**To configure SMTP virtual server components settings**

1. In IIS Manager, expand the local computer, expand Default SMTP
   Virtual Server, right-click the component you want to configure, and
   click Properties.
2. Change the default settings on the property pages as needed.

Comment: These instructions don't work for Windows XP.